# Build new instance of component from parent component and inject it into DOM? - Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am building a simple web app that, when a user pushes a button, will generate a new instance of a component and add it to the page.

However, I'm not sure how to generate a new instance of a component from the parent component's .js file..

The template:

```
{{yield}}

<div class="feed-tracks-container">
  {{#each model.tracks as |track|}}
    {{#feed-card track=track}}{{/feed-card}}
  {{/each}}
</div>

<div class="feed-controls-container">
  <div class="feed-control-container" style="width:25%" {{action (route-action "undoLastAction" track)}}>
    <img src="images/undo-btn.png"/>
  </div>
  <div id="skip-btn" class="feed-control-container" style="width:25%" {{action (route-action "skipTrack" track)}}>
    <img src="images/skip-btn.png"/>
  </div>
  <div id="share-btn" class="feed-control-container" style="width:25%" {{action (route-action "shareTrack" track)}}>
    <img src="images/share-btn.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="feed-control-container" style="width:25%" {{action (route-action "togglePreview" track)}}>
    <img src="images/preview-inactive-btn.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

The route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
     return {
       tracks: [
        {
          id: 1,
          track_name: "Karate",
          artist_name: "R3hab",
          track_length: 230,
          share_count: 10864,
          background_img: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR3oh8ADMDG3hVZ1I_9IJumqLXJNS2-TBPrxpUdRL8J_71H5I0kyw",
          waveform_img: "http://i.imgur.com/kP6KCJl.png"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          track_name: "Care",
          artist_name: "R3hab",
          track_length: 230,
          share_count: 1322,
          background_img: "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS5OsXpnek1SMJzol7hYnRt9QjNEHwPf1InRAKwoWocZWvMzPqo0w",
          waveform_img: "http://i.imgur.com/8o0AdWk.png"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          track_name: "Soundwave",
          artist_name: "R3hab",
          track_length: 230,
          share_count: 14554,
          background_img: "http://www.music-bazaar.com/album-images/vol17/800/800095/2652999-big/Soundwave-Extended-Mix-Single-cover.jpg",
          waveform_img: "http://i.imgur.com/8o0AdWk.png"
        }
      ] 
    }
  },
  actions: {
    skipTrack: function() {
      var new_track = {
        id: 6,
        track_name: "I'm new!",
        artist_name: "R3hab",
        track_length: 230,
        share_count: 14554,
        background_img: "http://www.music-bazaar.com/album-images/vol17/800/800095/2652999-big/Soundwave-Extended-Mix-Single-cover.jpg",
        waveform_img: "http://i.imgur.com/8o0AdWk.png"
      }
      var tracks = this.modelFor('feed').tracks;
      tracks.shift();
      tracks.pushObject(new_track);
    },
    shareTrack: function() {
      console.log("sharing");
    }
  },
});
```

**ANSWER**
I was not using `pushObject` when inserting the new object into the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//template
{{#each componentNames in componentName}}
  {{component componentName data=data}}
{{/each}}
```

Change the componentNames property in your controller. Should render a new component when you add to the componentNames array.

edit- swap component for controller, and it answers your question.

Comment: yes that worked! only this is, now when i remove an object from the array, the view updates before the animations are executed.. i wonder if there's a way to call the route from the component on animation completion

Comment: I mean, I don't know what you are getting at with the route thing, but what you'd want to do is apply your animation class to the component, then wrap the logic that removes it from the array in an Em.run.later.